# Error when install react native popup or dialog on ubuntu

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

when i tried to install `npm install --save react-native-dialog`
 to use this component in react-native i got this error

[image]

what is the problem ? i search in the Internet but cannot found the solution !

Comment: Your `package.json` file has a syntax error: `unexpected token 'r' at 16:6`, you're probably missing a comma.

Comment: my problem is here : npm WARN react-native-nav@1.1.4 requires a peer of react-native@>= 0.16 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-route-navigator@1.0.2 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.5 but none was installed.

Comment: Please paste your `package.json` file so that we can see where your error exactly is. The `npm WARN` messages shouldn't be of importance.